# Push Notification Alert comes app not openning when unlocking an iPhone in ios4.2

Tags: iphone, push-notification, push

My app sends push notifications in the form of UIAlertViews. When the device is not locked the UIAlertViews appear with two buttons and if the user taps on the right button my app is launched.

What I have noticed is that if the device is black screened to save power and the user taps on the home button and there is a push notification alert from my app with only the OK button waiting for him there, if he slides to unlock the device my alert is getting closed in ios4.2.

Can we control this not close alert but let the user choose his action with two buttons close or view.

OR
**EDIT: What is default behavior for this in ios4.2 and ios5?**

Please help me if any one knows this.

Comment: The user is choosing his action; they can either swipe the unlock to dismiss or swipe the notification to act on it. It's the same as cancel or view.

Answer (score 2):

Am afraid that this is not possible, this is the way apple designed the notification to be, when the device is locked the use does not have the option to close or open the app

Well iOs5 has the notification center, and in the lock screen the user can swipe the notification that he received and open the app that sent it

Comment: please my Edit tell me if know ans.